# hiding actions menu in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2007

i am using the following code to hide the Actions menu from Discussion Board list. The code is :

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.ms-menutoolbar td:lt(4)').hide(); 
    }); 
</script>
```

I found this from an article, but its not working.  Can you please help me regarding hiding Actions menu from Discussion Board list.

Also tried this code with no luck:

```
<script>
function HideDiv(name) {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
        var str = div[i].id;
        if (str.indexOf(name) >= 0) {
            var viewInExplorer = div[i];
            if (viewInExplorer != null) {
                if (viewInExplorer.parentNode != null)  
                    viewInExplorer.parentNode.removeChild(viewInExplorer);
            }
        }
    }
}
HideDiv("ListActionsMenu");
</script>
```

Comment: Try using jQuery for its performance is better than enumerating all DIVs on your site. Your `.ms-menutoolbar td:lt(4)` seems to be wrong - just try finding the correct element to hide (try different numbers). Check the source code to see where the "Actions" button actually sits within the DOM.

Comment: the above javascript(not jquery) code is working fine when i run this in firefox firebug(i.e, Actions menu is disappeared) but when i am placing that code in cewp, there is no effect in the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below script but i would suggest to use custom master page in which you just remove site action or apply a sharepoint security trim control so that it is visible to administrator only

```
<script type="text/javascript" > this.document.getElementById("siteactiontd").style.display = 'none'; </script>
```

Comment: thanks ashutosh. I have a doubt regarding sharepoint login. When i accessing a sharepoint site, it prompts for the user to enter username and password. If he clicks cancel button, the page is hsowing 401:unauthorized. I want to redirect the page to home(welcome)page when he clicks cancel button. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to think about using a Custom Action to hide the menu items:

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465980.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.ms-menutoolbar td:eq(2)').hide(); 
$('.ms-menutoolbar td:eq(3)').hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using JavaScript you can do this less complicated. Just find element `<td>` with `id="siteactiontd"` in masterpage and set style `style="visibility:hidden"` (using SharePoint Designer) like so:

[image]